# 'canvas is plane' from tikz external file is screwed

Tags: tikz-external

Using Overleaf, I do `input` of a `standalone` tikz figure defined like so:

```
% File diagram.tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pfgplots}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\makeatletter
\def\@setOxy O(#1,#2,#3)x(#4,#5,#6)y(#7,#8,#9)%
  {\def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
   \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{(#1+#4)}{(#2+#5)}{(#3+#6)}}%
   \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{(#1+#7)}{(#2+#8)}{(#3+#9)}}%
   \tikz@canvas@is@plane
  }
\tikzoption{canvas is plane}[]{\@setOxy#1}
\makeatother 

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{50}{70}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\begin{scope}[canvas is plane={O(1,2,0)x(0.35,0.8,0)y(0,0,1)}]
    \draw[dashed,lightgray] (0,0) rectangle (8,5);
    \begin{axis}[hide axis, unit vector ratio=1 1 1]
        % hidden for conciseness
    \end{axis}
\end{scope}
\draw (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north] {$\hat{\textbf{x}}$};
\draw (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=west] {$\hat{\textbf{y}}$};
\draw (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south] {$\hat{\textbf{z}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following image.

[image: standalone diagram compiled from diagram.tex]

However, when including the code in my main file, the `canvas is plane` get totally screwed.

```
\begin{figure}
    \input{diagram}
\end{figure}
```

[image: diagram when input from main.tex]

How should I do to keep the `canvas is plane` behaviour of the standalone compilation?

Comment: please show an example that produces the output that you show.

Comment: Your code produces an error: `Environment axis undefined`. If I guess, I can get it to compile, but it doesn't produce the output you show.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the `\usepackage{pgfplots}` which provides the `axis` environment.

Comment: In addition, I made an overleaf project with a minimum working example: https://www.overleaf.com/read/mdwbrmkvmvsn#8b674d. The `diagram.tex` can be compiled independently and produces a different result than when compiling with `main.tex`